# VBScript date format doesn't match locale

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vbscript, locale, date-format

We're maintaining an old classic ASP website for a client in the UK.

The locale ID (LCID) is set to 2057, which is as it should be. (I've tested and confirmed it using `Response.Write GetLocale`.)

The hosting server is set to UK locale as well.

Recently, we've transferred the website to another server (also with UK settings). Ever since the move, the pages display the date in American format. For example, instead of '16/05/2012,' the page shows '5/16/2012.'

The new server is practically identical to the old one (the old one has gone out of use for technical reasons).

What could be causing the date format to switch back to American format? I'm not sure whether to post this question here, or in [server fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: From your question it is not clear if you set the locale like `Session.LCID = 2057` on the new server.

Comment: @Guido I haven't set it per page, but I have tested it with `Response.Write GetLocale`, which gave me 2057.

Comment: As LCID is a session property, could it be your session expired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been having problems with this a lot, one moment it was ok, the next without any change it was wrong. Guess that IIS remembers the LCID from other pages. I decided to put on top of every asp page where dates are handled the statement "Session.LCID=XXXX" and now i haven't had problems with this for years.

Comment: I don't understand where the problem was (since `Response.Write GetLocale` printed 2057), but specifying `Session.LCID=2057` worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

setlocale only affects scripting engine locale setting.
Session.LCID affects scripting engine as well as ASP application